# How run a command in PowerShell from a specified directory and wait for it to complete before moving on?

Tags: powershell

I have a script that works to run an executable and wait until done in PS but I need to modify it to use a path defined in a variable earlier in the script.

Working:

```
$job = Start-Job `
    -InitializationScript { Set-Location C:\MyDirectory\ }  `
    -ScriptBlock { C:\MyDirectory\MyCmdLineExecutable.exe }
Wait-Job $job
Receive-Job $job
```

Not working:

```
$Path = "C:\MyDirectory\"
$ExePath = $path+"MyCmdLineExecutable.exe"
$job = Start-Job `
    -InitializationScript { Set-Location $Path }  `
    -ScriptBlock { $ExePath }
Wait-Job $job
Receive-Job $job
```

Here's the error:

```
Set-Location : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "path" is null. Change the value of argument "path" to a non-null value.
At line:1 char:2
+  Set-Location $Path
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Location], PSArgumentNullException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNull,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand


Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command                  
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------                  
49     Job49           BackgroundJob   Failed        False           localhost             $ExePath                
Running startup script threw an error: Cannot process argument because the value of argument "path" is null. Change the value of argument "path" to a non-null value..
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (localhost:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionStateBroken
```

Comment: If you want to wait for a program to complete, then why are you running it as a background job?

Comment: `Start-Process -Wait -WindowStyle Hidden` is the normal method.

Comment: It was the only way I could get it to run to competition before continuing.  I'm new at this Bill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining info from [Start-Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Start-Job?view=powershell-5.1#notes) docs with [About_Scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-5.1) article, I am certain of that you need to use `-InputObject` parameter:

> Specifies input to the command. Enter a variable that contains the
>   objects, or type a command or expression that generates the
>   objects.
>  In the value of the **ScriptBlock** parameter, use the
>   [`$Input` automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-5.1) to represent the input objects.

```
$Path = "C:\MyDirectory\"
$ExePath = $path+"MyCmdLineExecutable.exe"

$job = Start-Job -InputObject @( $Path, $ExePath) `
    -InitializationScript { <# $Input variable isn't defined here #> }  `
    -ScriptBlock { 
        $aux = $Input.GetEnumerator()
        Set-Location $aux[0]
        & $aux[1] }
Wait-Job $job
Receive-Job $job
```

BTW, to *run*  commands that are stored in variables and represented by strings, use [`&` Call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-5.1). See the difference:

```
$ExePath        ### output only
& $ExePath      ### invocation
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `Start-Process` with the `-Wait` parameter. You can also specify the `-WorkingDirectory` parameter to specify the working directory for the new process. Example:

```
Start-Process notepad -WorkingDirectory "C:\Program Files" -Wait
Write-Host "Finished"
```

When you run this script, Notepad will open but the script won't continue until it closes. When you close Notepad, the `Write-Host` line runs.

Comment: This doesn't address how to handle it with a variable execution folder.

Comment: You can use a variable for the `-WorkingDirectory` parameter if needed.